# git bash - Use git colors in printf output

Tags: colors, printf, git-bash

I've written a variant of git status. How do I use the green and red that git status uses for staged and unstaged changes to color my output? Preferably by finding the runtime git definitions of red and green, but that's not so important: a hard-coded solution will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git would probably use ANSI escape code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

This typically means that you use `-e` in `echo` or %b in printf (tested with Git for Windows 2.43.0):

```
declare color_red="\\e[1;31m"
declare color_none="\\e[0m"
declare color_green="\\e[1;32m"
echo -e "${color_red}RED${color_none}"
printf "%bRED%b" "${color_red}" "${color_none}"
```

Default git color are handled by the [`color.status.<slot>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorstatusltslotgt) and boolean `color.status`: I did not find default values using `git config` command but you can find a the code that's responsible for the *default* palette [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f41f85c9ec8d4d46de0fd5fded88db94d3ec8c11/wt-status.c#L41).

**Edit:** the colours above are colours that I use in my own projects. You can use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit) as reference.

[`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L262) use another variation of these colours: the difference with my colours are simply that I activated the *Bold or increased intensity*.

If your shell supports it (Windows Terminal does, most Terminals on Linux should), you can also try 24 bits colours:

```bash
echo -e '\e[38;2;255;0;0mRED\e[0m\e[38;2;0;255;0mGreen\e[0m'
```

If you need other escape sequence, then [this site](https://ansi.gabebanks.net/) can help you but it does not supports 24 bits colours.

Last but not least, here is a screenshot of what this does with Windows Terminal

[image]

Comment: Cheers; I found that these are the colors for local and remote branches when using `git log`. Replace with `e[0` in red and green and you get status colors, and `e[2` for darker shades.

Comment: git probably do not hard-code colours, so you should not recommend to do it. We have libraries, and sometime people want to disable colours. Let's fdo the job to a library!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't know OP intent but if his status wrapper is for himself, I don't see the problem with hard-coded colours. Otherwise, yes, you would have to allow disallowing them (in case of pipe) or use any git command that do that. Also, to be mentioned but some command like git log allow using simplified colors: `git log --pretty='format:%Cred%s%Creset'`. I don't know if you can "hack" this in the status to get actual colour.

Comment: It's for me and my coworkers. A more portable solution would be good to have, but this will do for now; I hesitate to accept because it's the wrong colors for what I asked for in OP as per my earlier comment.

Comment: See my answer because if the red/green I added are not the red/green you seek, then I don't see what I can do more :)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't your ''bold' output in fact "Reset or normal" while your 'not bold' is "Bold or increased intensity" according to the Wikipedia page you linked?

Comment: The reset is `\e[0m`

Comment: I'm talking about the first two rows in the SGR table, n=0 named "Reset or normal" and n=1 named "Bold or increased intensity". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code